# Declaring class as properties inside another class

Tags: c#, class, properties

I copied this code from [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-lazy-loading-in-C-Sharp-using-lazyt-class/) and I don't get any idea why define class inside classes as properties. Also, what happens when the class `PersonalLoan` is instantiated ?

```
public class PersonalLoan
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccounHolderName { get; set; }
    public Loan LoanDetail { get; set; }
    public PersonalLoan(string accountNumber)
    {
        this.AccountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.AccounHolderName = "Sourav";
        this.LoanDetail = new Loan(this.AccountNumber);
    }
}
public class Loan
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public float LoanAmount { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoanApproved { get; set; }
    public Loan(string accountNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loan loading started");
        this.AccountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.LoanAmount = 1000;
        this.IsLoanApproved = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Loan loading started");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you see one class as a property?

Comment: If you are asking about this `public Loan LoanDetail { get; set; }` , then it is [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). You may also see: [Difference between Composition and Aggregation](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/compagg07272007062838AM/compagg.aspx)

Comment: @Habib thanks can you please tell me what happens when the class 'PersonalLoan' is instantiated ?

Comment: Just pointing this out since the concept is related to money, but always use `decimal` for money. Their example is using `float` and that's just wrong.

Comment: @PatrickHofman i guess {get , set} is only used with the properties, please comment/answer

Comment: i am note sure about this , can u please answer this after re-reading the question

Comment: @PatrickHofman , i am Not sure why are u upvoted thrice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that this code snippet is an example of what you should avoid: `LoanDetail` property of type `Loan` inside a class `PersonalLoan` suggests a *has-a* relationship between the classes. In other words, the authors of this code snippet are trying to say that

*Personal loan has a Loan*

This, however, is unlikely the relationship that they are trying to model: in reality,

*Personal loan is a Loan*

The relationship *is-a* is modeled using inheritance, not composition. In other words, they should have written this:

```
public class PersonalLoan : Loan {
    public PersonalLoan(string accountNumber) : base(accountNumber) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Another issue that points to the model being incorrect is that both `PersonalLoan` and the `Loan` inside it have the same `accountNumber`, which is stored in two places within the same object. When you see this, you know something is not right. The reason you get two account numbers is that when `PersonalLoan` gets instantiated, its constructor also instantiates `Loan`, passing it the same `accountNumber`.

This is not to say that embedding objects inside other objects is wrong. For example, if you were to model a borrower address as a class, you would end up with something like this:

```
class Address {
    public string Country {get;set;}
    public string City {get;set;}
    ... // And so on
}
class Borrower {
    public Address MailingAddress  {get;set;}
    ... //
}
```

This model is perfectly valid, because *Borrower has an Address*.

Comment: it is about Lazy<T> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/implement-lazy-loading-in-C-Sharp-using-lazyt-class/

Comment: @Constantine The model the article at the link presents is not ideal, because it does not match reality closely enough to be intuitive to the readers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think the name is just wrong. It should be `LoanDetail` to match reality as I have seen close to the same structure in the real world. `MyLoanTypeObject` with `LoanDetails` child.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight can you please share what happens when the class is instantiated?

Comment: @Constantine I mentioned what happens at instantiation in the middle of the answer: basically, `Loan` object inside gets instantiated, so you end up with two objects - `PersonalLoan` on the outside, which references `Loan` inside.

Comment: @TyCobb If `Loan` represents loan details, `PersonalLoan` should not have its own `AccountNumber`, or at the very least do a calculated getter that returns `LoanDetail.AccountNumber` and have no setter.

Comment: @TyCobb i think you are stretching it to the wrong direction , i dont want to know about the Naming-Convention,Modelling-Approach etc , please help me by explaining what is happening when the class is instantiated.